# Vertical alignment in bootstrap's spans

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any work around for vertical alignment of elements or texts in bootstrap spans relative to other spans

For eg. if I have a row and spans like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span3" style="background-color:lightblue">Description</div>
   <div class="span9" style="background-color:pink">
   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  ....
   </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this

[image]

So is there a way to show "Description" vertically center of the next span's height?

Comment: If you know or fix the height of both spans, then you can try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/J6m8v/). Otherwise, you may look into tables or table-like displays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Center in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808445/vertically-center-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

try `display: table;` for parent and `display: table-cell;` for child

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/kjy1xafz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to vertically center an element for certain screen sizes you could always use media queries such as:

```
/*tablet*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  #logo{
    margin-top:70px;
  }
}
/*desktop*/
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  #logo{
    margin-top:20px;
  }
}
/*large desktop*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #logo{
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try out some [absolute centering tricks with CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/).  For example, if you're willing to: 1) declare the height of the div to be centered, and 2) Make your `.row-fluid` `position: relative;` then perhaps [this sample could work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/J6m8v/28/).

Resulting in the following DOM:

```
<div class="row-fluid relative">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="vercenter" style="background-color:lightblue">Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" style="background-color:pink">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.vercenter {
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot on this , and a  simple solution by using  `jquery`  is shown here !

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var relheight=$('.span9').height() / 2;
    $('.span3').css('margin-top', relheight) ;

});
</script>
```

It works and i tested it also . If you like my answer please vote for me

Comment: You should compute the relheight as `var relheight=($('.span9').height() - $('.span3').height()) / 2;` to vertically center the contents of the `.span3`

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap there is no provision for such issue. **It is implantation dependent**.
However you can write a css rule saying if next div exceeds the height of a previous div align the previous div at center height of next div & apply this class to the divs wherever you want this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script-free solution.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span3" style="background-color:lightblue;margin:0px auto;float:none;">Description</div>
   <div class="span9" style="background-color:pink;clear:both;margin:0px auto;float:none;">
   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  ....
   </div>
</div>
```

The code in action: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/v3aDM/)

Just remove the inline styling and place it in your css file.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.row').each(function() {
  var rowHeight = $(this).height();
  $(this).find("[class^='span']").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).height() < rowHeight-20) {
      var odstep = (rowHeight - $(this).height()) / 2 ; 
      $(this).css( "padding-top", odstep );
    }
  });
});
```