# Vertically centering .spans in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to vertically center my text in `.span6` with my image in a separate `.span6` right next to it. Both divs are contained in `.row-fluid`. My goal is for them to be vertically aligned with each other so they appear more vertically balanced.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">...</div>
  <div class="span6">...</div>
</div>
```

You can view the problem here:
http://theplaybook.co

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment in bootstrap's spans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303461/vertical-alignment-in-bootstraps-spans)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually found a solution that was more aesthetically pleasing. I added the images above the text and centered, which wasn't nearly as difficult to do. Plus it looked way better.